# Writing to SQL Database - ConnectionException - PySpark

Tags: database, apache-spark, pyspark, thrift, spark-thriftserver

I'm attempting to write a dataframe to OmniSci's database, basically a GPU-backed SQL database. I'm receiving a strange error when attempting to do so:

```
subs_dim.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mapd:EC2ADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9091:mapd").option("driver", "com.mapd.jdbc.MapDDriver").option("dbtable", "subs_dim").option("user", "mapd").option("password", "INSTANCEID").save()
```

and receiving this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection failed - org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o309.save.
>   : java.sql.SQLException: Connection failed - org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
>       at com.mapd.jdbc.MapDConnection.(MapDConnection.java:113)
>       at com.mapd.jdbc.MapDDriver.connect(MapDDriver.java:55)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:63)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:72)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:190)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:187)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:683)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:683)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:175)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:84)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:126)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:683)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:287)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:281)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
>       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
>       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Anyone have ideas? I've pinged the server and confirmed that port is open

Comment: Maybe, exception occurs on executor node, where server is not visible.

Comment: Hmm interesting theory. How would I go about rectifying that?

Comment: Executor computer (IP address)  where error occurs, can be found with Spark History server, or in other way. Then try to connect to server from this computer for confirm cause.